# Python requests getting 404 response

Tags: python, python-requests

I've used this same script on several other vbulletin forums and it works on all of them except this site. I've searched and searched, looked for typos etc... and just can't figure this out. I've created a dummy user account to log in with.

website = www.thereeftank.com
username imadummy
password Imadummy123

Here's my code, I'm getting a 404 response which I can't figure out.

```
import requests

r = requests.session()

forumURL = "http://www.thereeftank.com/forums/"

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
        'Referer': 'http://thereeftank.com/forums/'}

loginpayload = {
    'vb_login_username': 'imadummy',
    'vb_login_password': '',
    's': '',
    'securitytoken': 'guest',
    'do': 'login',
    'vb_login_md5password': '91af104d37ced6cc91958929b52be1bb',
    'vb_login_md5password_utf': '91af104d37ced6cc91958929b52be1bb'}


def login():
    loginURL = forumURL + 'login.php?do=login'

    z = r.post(loginURL, data=loginpayload, headers=headers)
    print z.url
    print z
    if 'Thank you for logging in, imadummy.' in z.text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print login()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check the response content in "z", you actually got

```
Invalid Redirect URL (http://thereeftank.com/forums/)
```

change your headers by adding "www." to your Referer url can fix this issue.

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
        'Referer': 'http://www.thereeftank.com/forums/'}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, really appreciate it. I originally was missing the www. from the forumURL and changed it there, but missed it on the referred.